# Pentaho's "Hadoop File Input" (Spoon) always displays error when trying to read a file from HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am new to Pentaho and Spoon and I am trying to process a file from a local Hadoop node with a "Hadoop file input" item in Spoon (Pentaho). The problem is that every URI I have tried so far seems to be incorrect. I don't know how to really connect to the HDFS from Pentaho.

To make it clear, the correct URI is:

> hdfs://localhost:9001/user/data/prueba_concepto/ListadoProductos_2017_02_13-15_59_con_id.csv

I know it's the correct one because I tested it via command-line and it perfectly works:

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://localhost:9001/user/data/prueba_concepto/ListadoProductos_2017_02_13-15_59_con_id.csv
```

So, setting the environment field to "static", here are some of the URIs I have tried in Spoon:

- hdfs://localhost:9001/user/data/prueba_concepto/ListadoProductos_2017_02_13-15_59_con_id.csv
- hdfs://localhost:8020/user/data/prueba_concepto/ListadoProductos_2017_02_13-15_59_con_id.csv
- hdfs://localhost:9001
- hdfs://localhost:9001/user/data/prueba_concepto/
- hdfs://localhost:9001/user/data/prueba_concepto
- hdfs:///

I even tried the solution Garci García gives here: [Pentaho Hadoop File Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430535/pentaho-hadoop-file-input)
which is setting the port to 8020 and use the following uri:

- hdfs://catalin:@localhost:8020/user/data/prueba_concepto/ListadoProductos_2017_02_13-15_59_con_id.csv

And then changed it back to 9001 and tried the same technique:

- hdfs://catalin:@localhost:9001/user/data/prueba_concepto/ListadoProductos_2017_02_13-15_59_con_id.csv

But still nothing worked for me ... everytime I press Mostrar Fichero(s)... button (Show file(s)), an error pops saying that that file cannot be found.

[I added a "Hadoop File Input" image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW5Ti.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so I actually solved this.

I had to add a new Hadoop Cluster from the tab "View" -> Right click on Hadoop Cluster -> New

There I had to input my HDFS Hadoop configuration:

- Storage: HDFS
- Hostname: localhost
- Port: 9001 (by default is 8020)
- Username: catalin
- Password: (no password)

After that, if you hit the "Test" button, some of the tests will fail. I solved the second one by copying all the configuration properties I had in my LOCAL Hadoop configuration file ($LOCAL_HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml) into the spoon's hadoop configuration file:

> data-integration/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/hadoop-configurations/hdp25/core-site.xml

After that, I had to modify the data-integration/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/plugin.properties and set the property "active.hadoop.configuration" to hdp25:

> active.hadoop.configuration=hdp25

Restart spoon and you're good to go.